# Can't access CompizConfig Settings Manager or terminal after installing Atlantis transparent cube plugin

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, ccsm, cube

I installed the Atlantis transparent cube plugin and now all I have on my screen are folders and fish.

I can't:

- open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- open the run dialogue box with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to do what I need (unity --reset)

I have been using the computer in guest mode, but I can't do this forever ...at least, I hope won't need to.

Comment: Isn't Ctl+Alt+F1 dedicated to "Switch to virtual terminal #1"? Did that work before installing Atlantis?

Comment: You may be able to open ccsm by loging in to a virtual terminal and typing the command "DISPLAY=':0.0' ccsm" and then switching back to the GUI with Ctl+Alt+F7.

Comment: Topically related: [How do I enable the Compiz Atlantis effect?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11656/955434) and [How to activate cube and related Compiz features without crashing Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/81887/955434)

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete your compiz config file.

Open a virtual console:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

stop the login manager:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

delete your compiz settings:

```
rm -rf .config/compiz-1/
```

start lightdm

```
sudo start lightdm
```

log into ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to open ccsm then simply open a folder on your Desktop & browse to /usr/share/applications.

Double left click on the Compizconfig Settings Manager icon.

If in similar with no folders on the Desktop then right click > create one, ect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another DE such as gnome shell you can configure compiz(by pressing reset button in preferences) from it and re-log to Unity read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81887/how-to-activate-cube-and-related-compiz-features-without-crashing-unity) also.